# How to set up flatbuffers in Android Studio - Gradle?

Tags: android-studio, eclipse, gradle

Just switching over from Eclipse to Android Studio. I think I'm supposed to use Gradle to automatically download dependencies from the web. Sounds great, but I can't get it working with anything, in particular Google's flatbuffers.

So I found the link on the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.davidmoten/flatbuffers-java/1.3.0.1), and I think I'm supposed to do something with the following:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.davidmoten/flatbuffers-java
compile group: 'com.github.davidmoten', name: 'flatbuffers-java', version: '1.3.0.1'
```

But the comments in my project's Gradle (which is supposed to be a library by the way - but that's another story...) says I should not place my "dependencies here" (see below)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So what am I supposed to do? I've heard of "modules" - so I could load flatbuffers in as a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was updating the wrong build.gradle. I was updating the gradle of the package within the "app". So having updated my `build.gradle` file (Module: app) to include the following last dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile group: 'com.github.davidmoten', name: 'flatbuffers-java', 
 version: '1.3.0.1'
}
```

it works nicely. Beginning to like AS now... hehe.

**UPDATE**

Been porting my stuff over to Android Studio today. I'm a total convert - very good and much easier than Eclipse.